# How to show page on GET request? It errors with HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have created a login page if i run the app it has the url (http://localhost:8080/MyApp/). If user successfully logged in then user is able to enter to inbox, and draft page. so my corresponding urls are http://localhost:8080/MyApp/MainMenu, http://localhost:8080/MyApp/inbox, http://localhost:8080/MyApp/draft etc. when i copy any of url and paste in browser I want to open the existing page. But I am getting `HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL` error message. I have implemented post method to submit any page. i cant use get method to submit login form etc. How can I get the corresponding page if i copy the page and paste it in browser?

Comment: **HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL**..  put this in google and see what u get..

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `doGet()` method to the servlets in question which just forwards to the desired JSPs.

E.g.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/inbox.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

If you already have them, then you'd need to remove any `super.doGet()` calls, otherwise you would still face the HTTP 405 error.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains some hello world examples demonstrating the same

Answer (score 0):

It Depends How you have Overrided the `doPost` or `doGet` Methods. The correct order of parameter 
should be :

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
```